# When keyboard appears the user can't scroll to the last 4 items in listview using a searchview

Tags: android, listview, keyboard, searchview

I have a `listview` with items and a `searchview` in my `toolbar`. When the user clicks on the search icon the keyboard appears. There's a problem which drives me nuts. When the keyboard appears the user can't scroll to the last four items and yes I tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, but they did nothing.

*Manifest:*

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name=".Adapter">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".OnSwipeTouchListener"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_on_swipe_touch_listener"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

*Activity.xml*

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="To get started please click the button below !"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mainlistview"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mainlistview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mainlistview"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.626" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Open m3u"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mainlistview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mainlistview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mainlistview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mainlistview" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainlistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="673dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-144dp">

    </ListView><![CDATA[



    />/>



]]>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: without keyboard]

I know there are billion questions to this problem, but literally nothing worked !!! Thanks in advance !
[image: with keyboard and max scrolling]

Comment: 1.May i ask is this a real device or an emulator ?
2.Does this happen with larger dataset for example 50 or you are unable after 15 as you had shown above ?

Comment: 1. It's a real device. 2. Yes, this happens with larger dataset, it doesn't matter

Comment: Try adding in the root view <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
and let me know to confirm

Comment: I just tried that, but I can still scroll to the 15. item. The keyboard covers up the last four items.

Comment: okay let's simplify as i did, just searchview and listview  in constraint
`<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainlistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView"/>`
try it and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

Try this:

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        final MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_search) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

*res/menu/toolbar_menu.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu>
   <item
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="@string/search"/>
</menu>
```

*Note*: I've populated the list of only 16 items using android:entries attribute
which has value of string-array (inside stars below)

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        **android:entries="@array/dummy_items"**
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
     />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And *styles.xml*

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
 <!-- whatever customization -->
```

*build.gradle*(The app one)

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzKHO.png)

#### Original answer

I would suggest to implement a `SearchDialog` Activity.
It shows a pop-up dialog for suggestions and, being a dialog,  doesn't go behind the keyboard.

Read this official Android guide for more information.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog#SearchDialog

Comment: But I don't want  to implement a SearchDialog ? That's why I'm here ? (no offense)